# Using BeginTransactionAsync() in different functions that also implement it

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have something similar to this:

```
public async Task Task1()
{
  await using var transaction = await _context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
  try
  {
    //Code goes here
    await OtherTask();
    await transaction.CommitAsync();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    throw new Exception(e.Message, e);
  }
}

public async Task OtherTask()
{
  await using var transaction = await _context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
  try
  {
    //Code goes here
    await transaction.CommitAsync();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    throw new Exception(e.Message, e);
  }
}
```

The problem that I'm having is that when I call `OtherTask()` and it tries to do the `BeginTransactionAsync()`, it says that one transaction already exist. Is there anyway I can fix this? I want to be able to call multiple functions, that when executed alone can have their own transaction, but when being called from a function which already has a transaction, to use that instead.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to fix this is to refactor the logic into a separate method:

```
public async Task Task1()
{
  await using var transaction = await _context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
  try
  {
    //Code goes here
    await OtherTask(transaction);
    await transaction.CommitAsync();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    throw new Exception(e.Message, e);
  }
}

public async Task OtherTask(Transaction transaction)
{
  //Code goes here
}

public async Task OtherTask()
{
  await using var transaction = await _context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
  try
  {
    await OtherTask(transaction);
    await transaction.CommitAsync();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    throw new Exception(e.Message, e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure I follow. Should I create a second method called OtherTask (same as the one I have, but with transaction as a parameter) which does pretty much the same thing, except the line with the `BeginTransactionAsync()` because it's already in the parameter. Am I correct?

Comment: @plasmy: You would create one `OtherTask(Transaction)` method and move all the db-modification code into it. Then that method can be called by `Task1` and also by the `OtherTask()` method. So `Task1` and `OtherTask()` will be called without existing transactions, and `OtherTask(Transaction)` will be called with an existing transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using EntityFramework Core.

DbContext.Database has a property CurrentTransation that will be null if neither BeginTransactionAsync nor UseTransaction have been called before.

```
public async Task Task1()
{
    
  await using var transaction = _context.Database.CurrentTransaction == null 
       ? await _context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync() 
       : _context.Database.UseTransaction(_context.Database.CurrentTransaction);
  try
  {
    //Code goes here
    await OtherTask();
    await transaction.CommitAsync();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    throw new Exception(e.Message, e);
  }
}

public async Task OtherTask()
{
  await using var transaction = _context.Database.CurrentTransaction == null 
       ? await _context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync() 
       : _context.Database.UseTransaction(_context.Database.CurrentTransaction);
  try
  {
    //Code goes here
    await transaction.CommitAsync();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    throw new Exception(e.Message, e);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and I got the following error: `Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IDbContextTransaction' to 'System.Data.Common.DbTransaction'`

Thanks for your help!